# App is in background or running when handling LocalNotification

Tags: iphone, localnotification

When the scheduled `NSLocalNotification` was fired, if the app is running , or user select the detail in alert while app is in the background, the app delegate's `didReceiveLocalNotification` will be called.

While in the `didReceiveLocalNotification` method, is there a way to tell the app is running or in the background ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState]` returns an `UIApplicationState`, which is defined as:

```
typedef enum {
   UIApplicationStateActive,
   UIApplicationStateInactive,
   UIApplicationStateBackground
} UIApplicationState;
```

Comment: Thank you, the app return from background, its state is inactive